# What is the best place to store user configurations settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modular-design

I am trying to develop a modular web aap using asp.net mvc 4. My question is that what is the best place to store the user settings, configuration and user access. Whether it is good to store it in db or good to store it in xml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer to go with XML.

**Advantages in XML file :**

- No need to access in your database server.(Which is contains valuable data)
- Anybody can understand and change the settings. (No need to know about SQL)
- Platform independent.

**Disadvanges in XML file :**

- Need to backup the file. To overcome this problem, Have to maintain the changes by history (It is a best way to revert it back).